# Fluent Validation: RuleForEach and also require the collection not be empty?

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I want to set a validator on each element in a collection *and* also require that collection not be empty. It would be nice to do this all in one line, but I don't know if I can or how to do that. Right now my best guess is to write two rules (where `Terms` is `IReadOnlyCollection<TermData>`:

```cs
RuleFor(x => x.Terms).NotEmpty();
RuleForEach(x => x.Terms).SetValidator(new TermDataValidator());
```

Is there a way to unify these two into one rule?

Comment: Try this `RuleFor(x => x.Terms).NotEmpty().ForEach(x=>x.SetValidator(new TermDataValidator()));`

Comment: @Loong Please post as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

`RuleFor(x => x.Terms).NotEmpty().ForEach(x=>x.SetValidator(new TermDataValidator()));`